# Inclined x-axis and grid lines in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to create a line highchart with inclined x-axis. The image gives a rough idea of what I want to achieve. I want the x-axis to be inclined and also the grid lines to be inclined from March as shown in the picture.

I could not attach picture, please look at following code(Please dont mind the beginner's coding to get the lines, i am still learning)

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 144.0, 176.0]        
    }]
}, function(c){
    c.renderer.arc(170, 330, 450, 0, -Math.PI/35, -Math.PI/35).attr({
    fill: '#FCFFC5',
    stroke: 'black',
    'stroke-width': 1
    }).add();
    c.renderer.arc(170, 215, 450, 0, -Math.PI/35, -Math.PI/35).attr({
    fill: '#FCFFC5',
    stroke: 'black',
    'stroke-width': 1
    }).add();    
});
```

included in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vijaykdotcom/Ff2nW/).

Also, I am trying to have a color for the range with the incline. As far as i have learnt, I can acheive this by combining area charts with the line so that area chart will act as a background to get the colors and inclination I want.
I looked for options in plotbands but could not find a way out.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm note sure if this what are you needed: http://jsfiddle.net/Ff2nW/42/

You can use `arearange` to achieve this:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },



    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 144.0, 176.0]        
    },{
        type: 'arearange',
        data: [[3,0,100],[11,25,125]]
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was looking for something like an inclined plotBand where the color band will start from the extreme left of plot area and extend till the extreme right (not starting at the first xaxis point and ending at the last). I have updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vijaykdotcom/Ff2nW/ to give an idea

Comment: If I could give a one place setting for horizontal inclination of xAxis/gridLines/plotBands..it would have been ideal, but may be I am dreaming here

Comment: Highcharts doesn't support that kind of plotBand, sorry. All you can do is to remove categories on xAxis, and set min and max padding to 0, see: http://jsfiddle.net/Ff2nW/57/

Comment: I also ended up with the same approach, I just used a max:10.5 for the xAxis. So far seems to solve my problem :). Thanks Pawel.